# Is my clojure code being AOT compiled?

Tags: java, maven, clojure

I have a Maven project where I mix java and Clojure code with the help of the clojure-maven-plugin.

I have a Clojure namespace like this:

```
(ns org.myproject.clojure
    (:gen-class))

(defn do-stuff [] (println "Doing stuff"))
```

And from java, I call it like:

```
IFn require = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require");
require.invoke(Clojure.read("org.myproject.clojure"));
IFn do_stuff = Clojure.var("org.myproject.clojure", "do-stuff");
do_stuff.invoke();
```

When running this code, "Doing stuff" is correctly being printed to the screen. Moreover, I can see .class files for my clojure code inside the generated jar from maven. Despite all that, I'm still not sure what's clojure doing when I require the namespace. Is it compiling the whole thing all over again? Or is my code being properly AOT compiled with my setup?

Finally, is there a way I can treat my clojure code as "regular" java functions? That is, importing org.myproject.clojure and calling do-stuff as a regular function? Given that clojure is generating bytecode for my code. I don't see why java couldn't call it being bytecode compatible.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question, but [this](http://clojure.org/compilation) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require does not compile your code, it loads the necessary classes dynamically. Your code is already compiled, unless of course you call `compile` yourself on another file.

Second, you cannot use Clojure functions as Java functions, because they are not the same thing. As you can see, Clojure functions are objects that implements `IFn` and have `invoke` methods. I don't think using directly Java methods would be feasible: you have to call methods on classes or instances, but which objects owns the methods? Further, using objects to implement functions means that they are truly first-class and that you can easily change bindings at runtime, which is what dynamicity is about.